# How to return a Boolean vector that tells whether element in vector A is in vector B?

Tags: r

Suppose I have two vectors, A and B. I want to get a boolean vector with the same length of vector A, which tells the information of each element in vector A whether it is in vector B. What is the function for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `%in%`:

```
A <- c(0,2,4,6)
B <- c(8,7,6,5,4)
A %in% B
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A <- c(0,2,4,6)
B <- c(8,7,6,5,4)
x <- (is.element(A, B))
x
## [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```